# How to redirect this URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect following URL

```
http://www.example.com/friends/view.php?l=ka&id=21903
```

Into this page

```
http://www.example.com/hello.html
```

How can I do this using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/friends/view\.php\?l=ka&id=21903\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/hello.html? [L,R]
```